# Can't Access The File Username.omg Because its being used by another process

Tags: c#, winforms

Can anyone help with this? I keep getting an error `File beeing used by another process`.

Here's my code so far:

```
string username = textBox1.Text;
string password = textBox2.Text;
string SecurityCode = textBox3.Text;
if(!Directory.Exists(path + "\\Login"))
      Directory.CreateDirectory(path + "\\Login");
if (!File.Exists(path + "\\Login\\Username.omg" + "\\Login\\Password.omg" + "\\Login\\SecurityCode.omg"))
    File.Create(path + "\\Login\\Username.omg");
    File.Create(path + "\\Login\\Password.omg");
    File.Create(path + "\\Login\\SecurityCode.omg");

    File.AppendAllText(path + "\\Login\\Username.omg", username);
    File.AppendAllText(path + "\\Login\\Password.omg", password);
    File.AppendAllText(path + "\\Login\\SecurityCode.omg", SecurityCode);
    MessageBox.Show("User Created: Welcome: " + username);
}
```

Comment: Delete the File.Create() calls.  Use File.WriteAllText() instead.

Answer (score 2):

[File.Create](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143360%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns a Stream that you need to close before trying to access the file just created

```
    using(File.Create(path + "\\Login\\Username.omg"))
        ;
    using(File.Create(path + "\\Login\\Password.omg"))
        ;
    using(File.Create(path + "\\Login\\SecurityCode.omg"))
        ;
```

a simple using statement around the File.Create call could help to close and dispose the returned stream

However, as stated in the comments above from [Mr Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant), your simple scenario could be served better by a simple call to File.WriteAllText()

```
File.WriteAllText(Path.Combine(path, @"login\username.omg"), username);
```

[File.WriteAllText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writealltext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) creates the file if it doesn't exist and overwrite its content if it exists. In your code, instead, you append the info to the same files over and over. 
I am not sure that this is really what you want here.

By the way, your call to File.Exists is wrong. You should test each file separately

```
string userNameFile = Path.Combine(path, @"login\username.omg");
if (!File.Exists(userNameFile)
{
    using(File.Create(userNameFile))
       ;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the quick reply works lovely thanks a lot :)

Comment: Please mark the correct answer. It may help others.